# Jupyter Lab kernel dies on import of library

Tags: python, jupyter, nest, jupyter-lab

I followed the instructions here (https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/user.html#user-install) to install NEST via the sudo apt-get install command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nest-simulator/nest
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nest
```

I do this to test it:

```
python3
import nest
```

and it doesn't work. Instead, it comes up with an error saying `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I've tried setting this up in a separate conda environment, where I reinstalled NEST, but I still get the same error.

FYI my system specs are Linux Mint 22.04, built on Ubuntu. Something that's confusing to me is that Ubuntu is built on debian, but they have 2 separate install instructions on their install page.
Version of python: 3.11.4
Version of NEST: 3.5

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. NEST simulator is only compatible with python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9, but not above. I'm going to try downgrading python to 3.9 and I think that will work.

Comment: downgrade python ?   you mean use a different version (virtual environment) for that one project...

Comment: yes, i've been having a problem with that, though. I'll post a question about it

Comment: that would be here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I've tried that, installing pyenv, adding it to my path, and then creating virtual environments, but it didn't work and my active version of python stayed as 3.11

Comment: if you have any suggestions you could add them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76830241/how-to-downgrade-python-3-11-3-to-python-3-9-on-linux-mint

Comment: personally (and i know it is poor practice), but i rarely use virtual environments. I tend to stick to the latest (at least major) versions of Python and if a package becomes legacy, i'd rather ditch the package than lose all the benefits of newer version for one package...

Comment: I would have don that too, but I need the package I'm using for a research project with my lab

Comment: then definitely the `virtual environment` for you in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).